# How to add servlet filter logic as jar to other maven project

Tags: java, maven, servlets, filter, executable-jar

I have created a logging project where it has servlet filter and added this as jar to other department service and when I call end point of department service logging filter is not getting called.

Comment: You likely forgot web-fragment.xml file. Put filter there. See abovelinked duplicate. It's not maven related.

Comment: hi @BalusC i have placed filter in web fragment.xml and added it as jar to my other project still the filter is not getting invoked .Can you please let me know any other configurations or changes need to be done other than this.TIA